# activerecord locking several rows at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, locking

I am trying to update several rows in a table which match some criteria (ie. all rows where some_col = "foo"). I want do this update as part of a transaction wherein I acquire a lock in share mode on all these rows, update row by row, and release the shared locks.

The documentation I have read so far talks about how to lock individual rows in ActiveRecord. But this will make things inefficient since I will have to first perform some .where(...) query, iterate through each row, and lock it (which refetches the row from the db). So I will be two db fetches per row...

I was wondering what is the best way to lock all rows which match a certain criteria in the .where(...) query itself. Is this possible? If not, are there better ways of locking a certain set of rows more efficiently. Locking the table is not an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pessimistic-locking

I we assume that your model is `Item` like in the example, do something like:

```
Item.lock.joins ....
```

e.t.c. and build the select you want so that you bring all the rows in a big view/result.

This might be what you want.

Comment: Does this work with the .where method? I just need to select multiple rows in a single table, so I don't want to incur the overhead of joins. I tried using Item.lock.where(:conditions) but it does not work. Suggestions?

Comment: It should be working. I just tried that on one of my projects and it worked. When you say that it does not work what error do you get?